# SQL Developer - 18.4 - autotrace

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

SQL Developer v 18.4

Problem: Autotrace not displaying executions statistics in SQL Developer

I think DBA gave me all the required privilege, I can select from views and autotrace (f6) works.
But somehow still not able to see execution statistics at right bottom of SQL developer windows pane.

SELECT on below view works

```
v$session
v$sql
v$sql_plan
v$sql_plan_statistics
v$sql_plan_statistics_all
v$sesstat
v$statname
v$mystat
```

Any ideas what I'm missing here? any setting or extra privileges needed here?
[image]

Comment: Please include a picture indicating your issue

Comment: @thatjeffsmith, thank you for the comment, I think I did look into few of your webpages if your username is correct. Trying to look into how to attach screenshot to stackoverflow since I don't use it regularly. Auto trace works, on first section we write query, 2nd section provide details on operation and 3rd section is empty with column heading V$STATNAME and V$MYSTATVALUE.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith, screenshot added, thanks.

Comment: User can select on v$session, v$sql, v$sql_plan, v$sql_plan_statistics, v$sql_plan_statistics_all, v$sesstat, v$statname, v$mystat.  Autotrace and statistics does gets displayed in sqlplus session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB: 12.1 - Select on V$PARAMETER was required.

```
-- AS SYS
SQL> GRANT SELECT on V_$PARAMETER to <USER>;
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need SELECT access on these VIEWs:

1. V$SQL_PLAN_STATISTICS_ALL
2. V$SQL
3. V$STATNAME
4. V$MYSTAT
5. V$PARAMETER

What's executed to get the plan and session stats:

```
select value
  from v$parameter
 where name ='statistics_level'

select value
  from v$parameter
 where name ='cursor_sharing'


select user,s.* 
  from v$sql_plan_statistics_all s  
 where hash_value = ? and child_number = ? 
 order by id

select hash_value, child_number
  from v$sql 
 where sql_id = ?  
 order by last_active_time desc

select sid,name,value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY pt.STATISTIC#) num 
  from V$STATNAME sn, V$mystat pt 
 where sn.STATISTIC# = pt.STATISTIC#
 order by lower(name
```

You can see all of this yourself by observing the output in the Log > Statements panel. This shows ALL of the SQL we run when you start typing, clicking buttons, etc in the GUI.

Comment: Thank you, I verified and listed and other views works with select, details added in original question.

Comment: Well your software is two years old, you could try upgrading to 20.4. And also, check out the log i referred to, you can see we're not running select * from queries...

Comment: Verified in 20.2 same thing, will look into Log > Statements panel. Sorry not much familiar with all section of SQL Developer so kind of still beginer :)

Comment: it appears I also required select on V$PARAMETER view for auto trace execution statistics to work. Do you think it's safe for DBA to grant this? Anyother alternative? Is this permission requirement new addition for 12.1 db for autotrace?